# Replacing a string using SQL Server Replace function - string has more than 4000 characters - what to do?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, string, replace

I have a table, where I need to replace some values in a column.

The database is running on SQL Server 2005.

The problem is that some of the rows contain more than 4000 characters, which is giving the `REPLACE` function some trouble, since it demands that I cast the first parameter to the datatype `NVARCHAR`, and therefore any characters exceeding 4000, is being truncated.

Is there any workaround for this, other than writing an application that handles this issue?

The query in question is:

```
SELECT 
   Replace(cast([Database].[dbo].[fruits].[Tekst] as NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'bananas', 'apples') 
FROM [Database].[dbo].[fruits]
```

The column `fruits` is of datatype `Text`

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Why would `nvarchar(max)` cause truncation at 4000 chars? What does this return for you? `SELECT LEN(REPLACE(REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),16000),'A','B'))` Are you sure your issue isn't simply that it is getting truncated in the SSMS results?

Comment: Because the maximumvalue of `nvarchar` is 4000: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx. The query you gave me returns the value 16000, but how can I make it iterate through a column to test for values? Replacing 'A' inside the cast with the column didn't solve the issue..

Comment: @MadsMadsDk - No `4000` is the maximum explicit value. Using `max` allows it to hold up to 2GB of data (a billion double byte characters)

Comment: @Martin - I tried to take the value which I thought had been truncated after 4000 chars, and copied it into notepad. All looks fine, and no truncation ocurred after all, so it's just in the SSMS results it's truncated. Thanks!

Comment: @madsmadsdk: the maximum for NVARCHAR(MAX) is **2 GByte** of data - roughly 250 times the volume of Tolstoj's `War and Peace` - enough for you!?!??!

Comment: @marc_s: Only just barely enough :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you have just hit the limit for an individual value in SSMS.

Annoyingly it doesn't allow you to set this to be unlimited and the only way I know of displaying long text is via casting to XML as below.

```
select
(select Replace(cast([Database].[dbo].[fruits].[Tekst] as NVARCHAR(MAX)),'bananas','apples')  AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
FROM [Database].[dbo].[fruits]
```

Answer (score 3):

This demonstrates how REPLACE can handle longer string

```
SELECT CAST(REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000) AS nvarchar(MAX)) +
               REPLICATE(N'def', 4000)  +
               REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000)

SELECT LEN(
       CAST(REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000) AS nvarchar(MAX)) +
               REPLICATE(N'def', 4000)  +
               REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000)
       ) --11997

SELECT REPLACE(CAST(REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000) AS nvarchar(MAX)) +
               REPLICATE(N'def', 4000)  +
               REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000), 'def', 'ddeeff')

SELECT LEN(
       REPLACE(CAST(REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000) AS nvarchar(MAX)) +
               REPLICATE(N'def', 4000)  +
               REPLICATE(N'abc', 4000), 'def', 'ddeeff')
       ) --15996
```